# gets the content of the annotated file in java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations

There is such an annotation

```
@Target (ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Question {}
```

and an annotated class

```
@Question
public class SomeQuestion {
  public void foo () {}
}
```

The problem now is, I want to get the source code of the annotated file in the annotation processor. In this case, I want to get this:

```
public class SomeQuestion {
public void foo () {}
}
```

How to do it? Help!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @AlexR I mean, is there any relevant annotation API to get the source code. For example, TypeElement already represents a type structure in the source file, so I think i can get the source code it represents, but it seems have no API about this information..

Comment: No.  There is no way to get the source.  Are you sure you need the source?  Or do you just need a list of the class’s methods?

Comment: @VGR I am sure I need the source, I came up with another workaround, just get the source file path and read the file, not by the annotation API. Though I think this is not perfect, but it can meet my needs.

Comment: May I ask why you need the source?

Comment: @VGR I want to annotate some code for just adding some meta info about the code. Then use the processor to covert the annotation with the source to markdown file. so I need the source code in the processor.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  I thought you wanted the source at runtime.  If you want to write a compile-time annotation processor, you must implement the [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) interface, and [specify your class’s name or location to the compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/javac.html#annotation-processing).  The RoundEnvironment given to your Processor’s `process` method will give you access to the TypeElements.